# $\pi/2$ rotation of spin $1/2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, rotation

$\def\ket#1{{\lvert #1 \rangle}}$

In John S. Townsend's *A Modern Approach to quantum Mechanics*, an operator is introduced in Ch. 2 that rotates the spin by $\pi/2$ in the $x$-$z$ plane.  These examples are given:

$$\ket{+x} = \hat{R}(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j}) \ket{+z}$$
$$\ket{-x} = \hat{R}(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j}) \ket{-z}$$

My question is: should that same operator also rotate:

- $\ket{+x}$ into $\ket{-z}$ and
- $\ket{-x}$ into $\ket{+z}$

so that applying it four times would get you back to the same state? If not? Why not? If so, what am I doing wrong here:
$$
\hat{R}(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j})\ket{+x} =
\hat{R}(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j})\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\ket{+z} + \ket{-z} \right) \right] \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\ket{+x} + \ket{-x} \right) \\
= \ket{+z}
$$
and similarly for $\hat{R}(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j})\ket{-x} = \ket{-z}$.

It looks like applying this operator twice brings you back to the same state.  I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Just want to give you fair warning, this question might be closed since it may be considered out-of-scope for this forum (as many "check-my-work" questions are). I provided an answer since it is closer to a "check-the-textbook-authors-work" question, but nevertheless, you might want to review these guidelines: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/

Comment: The reason check-my-work or homework-like questions are frowned upon is that they are usually answered be tedious checking that ultimately hinges on one small detail, and as such are usually deemed not helpful to the community at large

Comment: Thanks for the warning.  Maybe I should have given some background: I got my degree in physics over 20 years ago, and I recently decided to re-open my old QM book to see how much I still understand.  As I'm reading, I'm trying not to skip over stuff I don't really understand, but I don't have a professor I can go ask.

Comment: I think I'm still missing something conceptually.  How do you properly account for the phase?  The matrix applied to (|+x>, |-x>) gives (|-z>, |+z>), but now it's (|+z>, |-z>) that gets rotated into (|-x>, |+x>).

Comment: See the update to my answer. Also, no, $|-z>$ gets rotated into $-|-x>$, where there is a factor of -1 multiplying the ket $|-x>$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle}$

> In John S. Townsend's *A Modern Approach to quantum Mechanics*, an operator is introduced in Ch. 2 that rotates the spin by $\pi/2$ in the $x$-$z$ plane.  These examples are given:
>
> $$\ket{+x} = \hat{R}(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j}) \ket{+z}$$
> $$\ket{-x} = \hat{R}(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j}) \ket{-z}$$

The last equation is only true up to a phase (a factor of -1 in this case).

> My question is: should that same operator also rotate:
>
> - $\ket{+x}$ into $\ket{-z}$ and
> - $\ket{-x}$ into $\ket{+z}$

Yes, up to a phase.

> so that applying it four times would get you back to the same state? If not? Why not?

Yes, up to a phase.

For example, for spin-1: ${R(\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j})}^4 = R(2\pi) = 1$

But, for example, for spin-1/2: ${R(\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j})}^4 = R(2\pi) = -1$, which is funny, but nevertheless true.

> ...what am I doing wrong here...

The phase was not properly accounted for. For example:
$$
R(\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j})\ket{+z} = \ket{+x}
$$
$$
R(\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j})\ket{-z} = -\ket{-x}
$$

You can see this from, for example, the explicit matrix for the rotation operator:
$$
R(\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{j}) = 
\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix}\right) 
$$

---

**Update:**

In the $(|+z>, |-z>)$ basis the rotation matrix OP is interested in is
$$
R= \left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Therefore:
$$
R\ket{+z} = \left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \end{matrix}\right)
\equiv \ket{+x}
$$

Therefore:
$$
R\ket{-z} = \left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix} -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \end{matrix}\right)
=-\left(\begin{matrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ -1/\sqrt{2} \end{matrix}\right)
\equiv -\ket{-x}
$$

---

Note also, the rotation matrix for any angle in any direction, for spin-1/2, [can be written as](http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys622/ji/lecture21.pdf):
$$
R(\theta\mathbf{n}) = \cos(\theta/2)\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) - i\sin(\theta/2)\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot \mathbf{n}\;,
$$
where $\mathbf{\sigma}$ is a vector of the Pauli matrices.